# Command-line video editing in Linux (cut, join and preview)

Tags: linux, command-line, video-editing

I have rather simple editing needs - I need to cut up some videos, maybe insert some PNGs in between them, and join these videos (don't need transitions, effects, etc.). Basically, `pitivi` would do what I want - except, I use 640x480 30 fps AVI's from a camera, and as soon as I put in over a couple of minutes of that kind of material, `pitivi` starts freezing on preview, and thus becomes unusable.

So, I started looking for a command line tool for Linux; I guess only `ffmpeg` ([command line - Using ffmpeg to cut up video - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video)) and `mplayer` ([Sam - Edit video file with mencoder under linux](http://my.opera.com/allbits/blog/edit-avi-file-with-mencoder-under-linux)) are so far candidates, but I cannot find examples of the use I have in mind.

Basically, I'd imagine there's an encoder and player tools (like `ffmpeg` vs `ffplay`; or `mencoder` vs `mplayer`) - such that, to begin with, the edit sequence could be specified directly on the command line, preferably with frame resolution - a pseudocode would look like:

```
videnctool -compose --file=vid1.avi --start=00:00:30:12 --end=00:01:45:00 --file=vid2.avi --start=00:05:00:00 --end=00:07:12:25 --file=mypicture.png --duration=00:00:02:00 --file=vid3.avi --start=00:02:00:00 --end=00:02:45:10 --output=editedvid.avi
```

... or, it could have a "playlist" text file, like:

```
vid1.avi      00:00:30:12 00:01:45:00 
vid2.avi      00:05:00:00 00:07:12:25 
mypicture.png -           00:00:02:00
vid3.avi      00:02:00:00 00:02:45:10
```

... so it could be called with

```
videnctool -compose --playlist=playlist.txt --output=editedvid.avi
```

The idea here would be that all of the videos are in the same format - allowing the tool to avoid transcoding, and just do a "raw copy" instead (as in `mencoder`'s [copy](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Mencoder#copy) codec: "`-oac copy -ovc copy`") - or in lack of that, uncompressed audio/video would be OK (although it would eat a bit of space). In the case of the still image, the tool would use the encoding set by the video files.

The thing is, I can so far see that `mencoder` and `ffmpeg` can operate on individual files; e.g. cut a single section from a single file, or join files (`mencoder` also has [Edit Decision Lists (EDL)](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/edl.html), which can be used to do [frame-exact cutting](http://lists.mplayerhq.hu/pipermail/mencoder-users/2006-January/002614.html) - so you can define multiple cut regions, but it's again attributed to a single file). Which implies I have to work on cutting pieces first from individual files first (each of which would demand own temporary file on disk), and then joining them in a final video file.

I would then imagine, that there is a corresponding player tool, which can read the same command line option format / playlist file as the encoding tool - except it will not generate an output file, but instead play the video; e.g. in pseudocode:

```
vidplaytool --playlist=playlist.txt --start=00:01:14 --end=00:03:13
```

... and, given there's enough memory, it would generate a low-res video preview in RAM, and play it back in a window, while offering some limited interaction ( like `mplayer`'s [keyboard shortcuts](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=810568) for play, pause, rewind, step frame). Of course, I'd imagine the start and end times to refer to the entire playlist, and include any file that may end up in that region in the playlist.

Thus, the end result of all this would be: command line operation; no temporary files while doing the editing - and also no temporary files (nor transcoding) when rendering final output... which I myself think would be nice.

So, while I think that all of the above may be a bit of a stretch - does there exist anything that would approximate the workflow described above?

Comment: I also often use mkvmerge when I need to split/join videos.

Comment: Thank for that, @Vi. - had never heard about `mkvmerge` before, will make sure I check it out.. Cheers!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, there is. Try using the app called "Melt". See the documentation [here](https://www.mltframework.org/docs/melt/).

If you use a Debian derived distro:

```
apt-get install melt
```

Comment: on mac: `brew install mlt`

Answer (score 28):

Ok, since I cannot find much about `melt` command line usage, here are some notes.. (and after this, see this answer [Using process substitution to trick programs expecting files, with specific extensions as argument? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181673/using-process-substitution-to-trick-programs-expecting-files-with-specific-exte/186404#186404) for a script example via `bash`)

To begin with - there is a Ubuntu/Debian package for `melt` (I have Ubuntu 11.04 with MLT melt 0.6.2); the link given by [@Ielton](https://superuser.com/a/371030/39752) is for the "Media Lovin' Toolkit" (MLT) Wiki, which `melt` is a part of (but also `openshot` and `kdenlive`). Here is the link to the documentation text files from their git: [mltframework.org/mlt.git/tree - docs/](http://mltframework.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=mltframework.org/mlt.git;a=tree;f=docs;hb=HEAD); note the wiki has a page about [BuildScripts](http://www.mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/BuildScripts).

*For now, the biggest (only) problem I have with it, is that I cannot find a way to export an uncompressed video composition (either as `png` frames, or some uncompressed video format).*

First, in command-line `melt` you can control playback through frames; for instance, to "create" a 15-frame long white blank, and view it with the built-in `melt` player, use

```
melt -blank 15
```

When you view with `melt`, you will also get a command line info to `stderr` for the built-in player:

```
$ melt -blank 15 
+-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+
|1=-10| |2= -5| |3= -2| |4= -1| |5=  0| |6=  1| |7=  2| |8=  5| |9= 10|
+-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+ +-----+
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               H = back 1 minute,  L = forward 1 minute              |
|                 h = previous frame,  l = next frame                 |
|           g = start of clip, j = next clip, k = previous clip       |
|                0 = restart, q = quit, space = play                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
Current Position:         15
```

Once `melt` is done playing back, it will not exit - so you should type `q` to exit it.

We should note there are so-called "producers" and "consumers" in `melt`. If nothing is specified, then the default "consumer" is an [SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer)](http://www.libsdl.org/) window playing back the video; so the above command is the same as:

```
melt -blank 15 -consumer sdl
```

Thus, if we want to save what `melt` displays, we should change the consumer to something that will support a file format. To get a list of consumers:

```
$ melt -query "consumers"
---
consumers:
  - sdl
  - sdl_audio
  - sdl_preview
  - sdl_still
  - gtk2_preview
  - avformat
  - libdv
  - xml
  - decklink
  - null
...
```

The `libdv` consumer will output DV formatted data directly to `stdout`, so to save the video to a `.dv` file you'd do:

```
melt -blank 15 -consumer libdv > test.dv
```

Note that from the listed consumers, the only format I have tried, that can also be opened in another application is `libdv` (I used `vlc` as another application); however, this may fail for a different type of transcoding (*e.g. if instead of a blank, I try to convert a snippet from an `.flv` file, the resulting .dv file opens and plays in `vlc`, but is corrupt*).

Now for the **editing** part; essentially, you can specify a series of *file-name*/in/out  stanzas directly on the command line; say you have a file, `video.avi` - then you could do:

```
melt video.avi in=30 out=79 -blank 15 video.avi in=30 out=79
```

or slightly better formatted:

```
melt \ 
video.avi in=30 out=79 \ 
-blank 15 \
video.avi in=30 out=79
```

This means `video.avi` from its frame 30 to its frame 79 will be played; then a 15-frame blank; and then the `video.avi` sequence from frame 30 to frame 79 again.

To utilize images (say, `.png`) in a video edit composition:

```
melt \
video.avi in=30 out=79 \
test.png in=0 out=15 \
video.avi in=30 out=79 \
-blank 15
```

Note that for `test.png`, `in=` parameter doesn't need to be 0 - however, the image will be displayed for `out`-`in` time; in this case, it would be easiest to simply leave the `in=0` parameter out altogether.

The good thing is that this editing sequence can be saved - or as `melt` calls it, **serialized** - to a file; note there are *two* ways of such serialization: "simple" or XML. For instance, to save the above command as a "simple" serialized file, we can just add the `-serialise [filename]` switch to the command:

```
$ melt video.avi in=30 out=79 -blank 15 video.avi in=30 out=79 -serialise file.melt 
Project saved as file.melt.
```

Now the `file.melt` contains:

```
video.avi
in=30
out=79
-blank
15
video.avi
in=30
out=79
```

Seemingly, this "simple" serialized file format doesn't contain a "commenting" character - if I try to add a "`# comment`" line, `melt` complains with: '*Failed to load "# comment"*' (but apart from that, seems that such a line is ignored, and playback continues anyways). "`.melt`" seems to be an extension that `melt` recognizes as simple serialized file.

Now, to re-play back this serialized file, we could in principle just call `melt file.melt` - however, a more complete command line would be:

```
melt melt_file:file.melt -consumer sdl
```

... which would mean: use the `melt_file` "producer" to open `file.melt`, and render its frames on the "consumer" `sdl` (window).

Note that I have the experience, that (say) `.flv` videos play without a problem on the command line - however, cause a segmentation fault when they are specified in the `file.melt` serialized file! `.dv` videos produced by `melt` itself, seem to work fine in `file.melt`...

The XML type of serialization can be achieved by using the `-consumer xml:` switch (*instead of `-serialise`*) - so the above example would now be:

```
melt video.avi in=30 out=79 -blank 15 video.avi in=30 out=79 -consumer xml:file.mlt
```

To "play back" the newly generated `file.mlt` XML file, one can now do directly `melt file.mlt` - or, a more complete command line would be:

```
melt xml:file.mlt -consumer sdl
```

... which would mean: use the `xml` "producer" (*note, previously it was a consumer*) to open `file.mlt`, and render its frames on the "consumer" `sdl` (window).

Note that in this case, I've experienced that the very same `.flv` videos that caused segfault with a simple serialization file - work just fine with an XML serialization file!

In this case, the resulting `file.mlt` XML file has a lot more settings, such as resolution, frame rate, codec information etc - but it is also more difficult to work with in a text editor directly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mlt root="/path/to" title="video.avi">
  <profile description="automatic" width="320" height="240" progressive="1" sample_aspect_num="1" sample_aspect_den="1" display_aspect_num="320" display_aspect_den="240" frame_rate_num="25" frame_rate_den="1" colorspace="601"/>
  <producer id="producer0" in="30" out="79">
    <property name="mlt_type">producer</property>
    <property name="aspect_ratio">1.000000</property>
    <property name="length">125</property>
    <property name="eof">pause</property>
    <property name="resource">video.avi</property>
    <property name="meta.media.nb_streams">2</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.stream.type">video</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.stream.frame_rate">25.000000</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.stream.sample_aspect_ratio">0.000000</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.frame_rate">25.000000</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.pix_fmt">yuv420p</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.sample_aspect_ratio">1.000000</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.colorspace">601</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.name">mpeg4</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.long_name">MPEG-4 part 2</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.bit_rate">0</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.stream.type">audio</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.sample_fmt">s16</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.sample_rate">22050</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.channels">1</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.name">mp2</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.long_name">MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2)</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.bit_rate">64000</property>
    <property name="seekable">1</property>
    <property name="meta.media.sample_aspect_num">1</property>
    <property name="meta.media.sample_aspect_den">1</property>
    <property name="meta.attr.title.markup"></property>
    <property name="meta.attr.author.markup"></property>
    <property name="meta.attr.copyright.markup"></property>
    <property name="meta.attr.comment.markup"></property>
    <property name="meta.attr.album.markup"></property>
    <property name="audio_index">1</property>
    <property name="video_index">0</property>
    <property name="mlt_service">avformat</property>
  </producer>
  <producer id="producer1" in="30" out="79">
    <property name="mlt_type">producer</property>
    <property name="aspect_ratio">1.000000</property>
    <property name="length">125</property>
    <property name="eof">pause</property>
    <property name="resource">video.avi</property>
    <property name="meta.media.nb_streams">2</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.stream.type">video</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.stream.frame_rate">25.000000</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.stream.sample_aspect_ratio">0.000000</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.frame_rate">25.000000</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.pix_fmt">yuv420p</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.sample_aspect_ratio">1.000000</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.colorspace">601</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.name">mpeg4</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.long_name">MPEG-4 part 2</property>
    <property name="meta.media.0.codec.bit_rate">0</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.stream.type">audio</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.sample_fmt">s16</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.sample_rate">22050</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.channels">1</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.name">mp2</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.long_name">MP2 (MPEG audio layer 2)</property>
    <property name="meta.media.1.codec.bit_rate">64000</property>
    <property name="seekable">1</property>
    <property name="meta.media.sample_aspect_num">1</property>
    <property name="meta.media.sample_aspect_den">1</property>
    <property name="meta.attr.title.markup"></property>
    <property name="meta.attr.author.markup"></property>
    <property name="meta.attr.copyright.markup"></property>
    <property name="meta.attr.comment.markup"></property>
    <property name="meta.attr.album.markup"></property>
    <property name="audio_index">1</property>
    <property name="video_index">0</property>
    <property name="mlt_service">avformat</property>
  </producer>
  <playlist id="playlist0">
    <entry producer="producer0" in="0" out="49"/>
    <blank length="16"/>
    <entry producer="producer1" in="0" out="49"/>
  </playlist>
  <tractor id="tractor0" title="video.avi" global_feed="1" in="0" out="115">
    <track producer="playlist0"/>
  </tractor>
</mlt>
```

Comment: Also, here is an example for frame-accurate cuts: [Accurately cut video files from command line - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/458761/accurately-cut-video-files-from-command-line/1289110#1289110)

Comment: The links at the beginning in this answer are dead. Meanwhile there's a good explanation about the most basic fundamentals found on the page of the MLT-Framework: https://www.mltframework.org/docs/melt/

Answer (score 8):

The ffmpeg solution to this problem looks something like this:

```
mkfifo temp1 temp2 temp3
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -ss 30 -to 60 -c copy output.wmv temp1 2> /dev/null & \
ffmpeg -i input2.wmv -t 60 -c copy temp2 2> /dev/null & \
ffmpeg -i input3.wmv -i image.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] \
overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy temp3 2> /dev/null & \
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i "concat:temp1|temp2|temp3" -c copy output.mp4
```

It uses named pipes, so there's no creating temp files on disk, and allows you to cut up chunks of the video clips, and add images.

This examples uses time 30-60 of the first input, and then adds the first minute of the second input, then inserts a image file, and then the entire third video.

Code lifted from:

ffmpeg concatenate page:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

superuser page [Using ffmpeg to cut up video](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video)

superuser page https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/add-an-image-in-front-of-video-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks for that, I also recently learned of [ffmpeg-concat](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-concat), which is written in JavaScript (and you need `npm` to install it), so I thought I'd mention it

Comment: I would argue that using ffmpeg for video editing is ok for a very short video, image slideshow, etc. When you need to edit a complex video with hundreds of scenes, it seems more reasonable to use a video editor such as flowblade to do the cutting and then either directly export the video from the video editor, or export the project to MLT XML file and use either MLT or ffmpeg to do the actual transcoding.

Answer (score 6):

I too have been looking for such a tool and it does appear that melt is the tool for the job, however the documentation is almost impossible to understand/missing. You can do almost any combination of editing. I had some 'action cam' footage... the sound was unusable though. I joined the (h264) video together, added a 60 frame fade and replaced sound with a sound track
using:

```
% melt -video-track vid1.avi vid2.avi -mix 60 -mixer luma vid3.avi \
   -mix 60 -mixer luma -audio-track vorbis:track1.ogg vorbis:track2.ogg \
   -consumer avformat:OUT.avi acodec=libmp3lame vcodec=libx264
```

You can read more about it [here](http://mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/MltMelt). The main website is [here](http://www.mltframework.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you need something dead simple, then maybe you can use this tool I created (which uses ffmpeg) called EDITLY.

Here's how to use it in your case:

```bsh
npm install -g editly
```

Create a file `edit.json5`, with this content:

```js
{
  defaults: {
    // editly defaults to randomizing transitions, but since you wanted no transitions, set it to null
    transition: null,
  },
  clips: [
    // cutFrom/cutTo values are in seconds
    { layers: [{ type: 'video', path: 'vid1.avi', cutFrom: 30.12, cutTo: 105 },
    { layers: [{ type: 'video', path: 'vid2.avi', cutFrom: 300, cutTo: 432.25 },
    { duration: 2, layers: [{ type: 'image', path: 'mypicture.png' },
    { layers: [{ type: 'video', path: 'vid3.avi', cutFrom: 120, cutTo: 165.1 },
  ],
}
```

Now run:

```bsh
editly edit.json5 --out editedvid.mp4
```

You may also want some of the other features like title screens, text or subtitle overlay and generated backgrounds.

See project page for more info: https://github.com/mifi/editly

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, **and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question**.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Have now added a more detailed explanation

Comment: Perfect. Well done :)