# Cut WMV file into segments based on frame numbers and reencode to x264

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing

I've done a bit of work with FFMPEG in my days and I am somewhat familiar with VirtualDub as well as high-end products such as Sony Vegas.

However, I still can't figure out a simple and straight-forward way to extract frames M to N out of a given WMV file and encode that into an x264-encoded video.

I use Windows 7 64-bit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You first have to [figure out the start time of the first frame](https://superuser.com/a/459488/48078) in `HH:MM:SS.msec` format, or in `S.msec`. Then, where `<start>` is the timecode:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -ss <start> -c:v libx264 -frames:v 123 output.mp4
```

If you want to use filters you could do something like this, where `100` is the frame to start from:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -filter:v "select=gte(n\,100)" -c:v libx264 -frames:v 123 -vsync 0 output.mp4
```

Comment: I unfortunately could not test these commands, so please let me know if this does not work for you.