# Where to cut audio by video frame?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to cut the audio from frame 2928 to frame 5177 of a 23.976 fps blu-ray-movie.

I have read through some articles but don't see how to do that accurate.

[Cutting videos at exact frames with ffmpeg select filter](https://superuser.com/questions/866144/cutting-videos-at-exact-frames-with-ffmpeg-select-filter)

https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25291/how-to-precisely-trim-video-with-ffmpeg-ss-and-t-are-off-by-more-than-a-half

[How to cut at exact frames using ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/459313/how-to-cut-at-exact-frames-using-ffmpeg)

From my point of view  I have to extract the audio first:

`ffmpeg.exe -i movie.mkv -map 0:1 -c:a flac -sample_fmt:a s16 audio.flac`

Check if audio and video starts at the same time:

`ffprobe -show_entries stream=codec_type,start_time -v 0 -of compact=p=1:nk=0 movie.mkv
stream|codec_type=video|start_time=0.000000
stream|codec_type=audio|start_time=0.000000`

And cut the audio with frame/time-calculation:

`ffmpeg.exe -i audio.flac -ss (2928/(24000/1001)) -to (5177/(24000/1001)) -codec flac audio_cut.flac
ffmpeg.exe -i audio.flac -ss 122.122 -to 215.9240417 -codec flac audio_cut.flac`

A frame is a moment in time for video but a time slot for audio.
So I have to include frame 2928 and frame 5177.
But I'm not sure, where I have to start and stop the cutting.

From ffmpeg-documentation:

-ss: When used as an output option [...] decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach position.

-to: Stop writing the output or reading the input at position.

So when I want to extract audio for first frame I have to cut like this:

`ffmpeg.exe -i audio.flac -ss (0/(24000/1001)) -to (1/(24000/1001)) -codec flac audio_cut.flac`

With that in mind I have to cut for 2928 to 5177 like this:

`ffmpeg.exe -i audio.flac -ss (2927/(24000/1001)) -to (5177/(24000/1001)) -codec flac audio_cut.flac`

Is that correct?

Comment: With audio you need to cut at a natural zero crossing, or add a fade, otherwise you get clicks. I'm sure it would be a lot simpler in some graphical editor, even the freeware Audacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg starts to count at 0.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i audio.flac -ss (2927/(24000/1001)) -to (5177/(24000/1001)) -codec flac audio_cut.flac
```

--> 2927 - 5176

```
ffmpeg.exe -i audio.flac -ss (2928/(24000/1001)) -to (5178/(24000/1001)) -codec flac audio_cut.flac
```

--> 2928 - 5177

I need to cut until 5178 to get the audio from frame 5177.