# FFMPEG to extract first 15 seconds of a stream of mov or mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there a way to use ffmpeg to extract say first 15seconds of a video file (mov or mp4)? The input file will be passed in as a stream. 
I've looked at this https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper, but not sure if supports stream input. Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am looking at this https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper/tree/master/src/main/java/net/bramp/ffmpeg , but not sure I see what I need. Many thanks for your comment

Comment: @DavidPostill Can you please open the question now?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Hint: [ffmpeg Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

Comment: Guess I've already clearly mentioned that I don't find a way to use an input stream (java) on the documentation. Not sure what other information I can provide. If someone can guide me to the appropriate documentation that would help.I m not asking for an entire code/script.

Comment: See the link in the duplicate question banner. [command line - Using ffmpeg to cut up video - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, unless someone does not understand what I am asking? I have asked about a java implementation and have also asked about streaming implementation.Don't see how a command line related question can be treated as an equivalent.

Comment: If you are asking about a Java implementation then it is off topic, as programming questions are off topic.