# Why is Handbrake forcing down the frame size of my video?

Tags: video, compression, handbrake

**Summary:** I have an old movie that I downloaded from YouTube some years ago, saved as an flv. I want to extract a 13-minute clip from it. To do that, I used ffmpeg to convert it to mp4 so I could load it in DaVinci, where I extracted the clip. Then I used Handbrake to compress it. But when I did that, HandBrake reduced the frame size significantly, and the compressed clip is somewhat blurred compared to the original.

Why is HandBrake forcing that reduction in frame size, and how can I get it to output at the correct frame size?

**Details:**

The flv file is 268 MB, duration 107 minutes, frame size 318x240, frame rate 25:

[image]

The [ffmpeg command](https://www.reddit.com/r/VideoEditing/comments/3yn9wg/flv_to_davinci_resolve/) I used to convert to mp4:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -c copy output.mp4
```

That took about a second. The result is 264 MB:

[image]

I loaded that in DaVinci, extracted the clip, then rendered as mp4, H.265, 318x240, 25 fps:

[image]

The result of that is 51.4 MB, 13:19 mm:ss. MediaInfo reports it is HEVC, which I understand means it is in H.265, as I requested:

[image]

The size-to-time ratio is a lot bigger than for the full movie:

- Movie: 264 MB / 107 minutes = 2.5 MB/min.
- Clip: 51.4 MB / 13.33 min. = 3.9 MB/min.

When I load the clip in HandBrake, it tells me the source is 318x240, 25 fps. Even though it's in H.265, HandBrake tells me it's in H.264. Then HandBrake also contradicts its source information by saying under "Tracks" that it is 30 fps and that the size is 234x174.

[image]

```
========================
```

In Handbrake's "Video" tab, the encoder comes up as H.264 and the frame rate as 30. The RF is 22:

[image]

```
========================
```

I changed that to 265 and 25:

[image]

```
========================
```

The "Dimensions" tab says again that the size is 318x240, but then says that:

> **The scaled size and the final storage size are 234x174. I tried clicking several things and cannot get it to change that output size.**

[image]

```
========================
```

When I run that, the output is 22 MB, which is a nice reduction in file size:

- Compressed clip: 22 MB / 13.33 min. = 1.7 MB/min.

But the frame size is 234x174:

[image]

The video is somewhat blurred compared to the original, which it seems could well be caused by the reduced frame size.

Original flv file:
[image]

Mp4 converted by Ffmpeg:
[image]

Clip rendered by DaVinci.

> **This might give a clue to the problem. The image occupies less than the full window of the player. Did DaVinci reduce the scale of the video?**

[image]

Clip compressed by HandBrake:
[image]

Why is HandBrake forcing that reduction in frame size, and how can I get it to output at the correct frame size?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using FFMPEG to do the clipping? It should be completely capable of that.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't make much sense using Handbrake in this context, for your intended purpose. And what you're seeing is not the characteristics of the loaded video but the settings of the preset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit from the questioner: I've accepted this answer because it gave me what I needed. But see further details in the additional answer that I've also given.

---

---

It may be helpful to remember that Handbrake is largely a skin for FFMPEG with some relatively user-friendly presets. Your process is currently going FFMPEG > DaVinci > FFMPEG, without any real reason we can see for the additional steps. So skip all of the intermediary steps and just use FFMPEG to clip the video. Here's another question that may cover the basics of your need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420296/how-to-extract-time-accurate-video-segments-with-ffmpeg

Specify the clip start time with `-ss 00:00:00` and the end with `-to 00:00:00`. Like this example from the question I've linked just above:

```
ffmpeg -y -i [INPUT.file] -ss 00:42:42 -to 00:84:84 -codec copy [OUTPUT.file]
```

Doing this you're removing all the possibility of issues caused by the multiple steps you're currently using.

Comment: Since I'm starting with an flv file, shouldn't `-codec copy` instead be something that specifies conversion to H.265?

Comment: Why? Do you feel you need to? The goal in your question is only to get the clip, right? The file size is already small enough I don't see any obvious reason why you'd want to re-encode the file prior to clipping, but if you want to you should be able to do any other encoding you want in the same pass: https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video

Comment: No, the goal is to get the clip in as small a file as possible with the same quality as the original. That's why I used HandBrake. In the link you gave, I don't see anything about specifying the codec.

Comment: It shows that you can.

Comment: I've accepted your answer and also provided an additional answer showing the result of specifying the codec. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Mark yours as the answer, because it is, and just give me an upvote for recognition. That's all fine. I don't need more rep.

Answer (score 1):

I'm accepting the answer by "music2myear" because it gave me what I needed. But for some reason, it assumed I didn't care about the size of the output file. But I do care about that, which is the reason I was running HandBrake.

So I changed the `codec` parameter in that answer. Here is a summary of my results:

- Clip from DaVinci in H.265: 51.4 MB
- DaVinci clip then HandBrake: 22.0 MB (blurry)
- Clip from FFmpeg with `-codec copy`: 29.5 MB
- Clip from FFmpeg with `-codec:v hevc -codec:a copy`: 15.2 MB

Both FFmpeg results appear to have good quality. The one with codec `copy` took about a second, the one with `hevc`, about a minute.

The result from mFFmpeg with codec `hevc` gave a very nice reduction in file size:

- Movie: 264 MB / 107 minutes = 2.5 MB/min.
- Clip from DaVinci: 51.4 MB / 13.33 min. = 3.9 MB/min.
- Clip from FFMpeg with codec `hevc`: 15.2 MB / 13.33 min = 1.1 MB/min.

So, I don't have an answer to why HandBrake (or the combination of DaVinci and HandBrake) was reducing the frame size. But I do have answer for how to get good quality output with the right frame size (and an efficient file size), which is to **use FFmpeg directly**.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work-around, rather than an exact answer: do the whole process in a single step using a GUI that gives complete control of how the output is saved.

Two free, open source, video editors, [Shotcut](https://shotcut.org) and [OpenShot](https://www.openshot.org) (both available in Linux, and Mac, as well as Windows versions, and both Windows app run under *wine*, too, on this Ubuntu machine), for example, can open FLV video files, edit them, and save the edited output in various formats and with adjustable resolution and quality. There are many [alternative video editors](https://alternativeto.net/software/shotcut/), too.

[image: OpenShot Export Video Dialog]

The screenshot above is from the *OpenShot Export Video* dialog, and *ShotCut* offers even more granular control of output. One selects the segments to edit, applies filters such as *Sharpen*, if desired, and exports with color gamut (e.g., Broadcast, MPEG or JPEG), resolution, frame rate, compression, etc. under user control, all with a single tool. Neither program is intimidating to use, since reasonable defaults are preset.